# Windows key + Enter to swap between keyboards

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Prior to the big last windows update (1909) my keyboard seetings looked like this and I could easilly swap between options with Win + space

[image: previously]

Now it appears like this and the keyboard shortcut changed to Alt + Shift

[image]

Can I change it back to the first option? is it related to the update or any configuration?

Comment: What is "the big last windows update"? Are you using 1909 or already 2004?

Comment: @Robert sorry I didn't check that previously, i have 1909

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, and unless you've customized it otherwise, it's the Alt-Shift key combo that does that, or am I missing something?

Comment: Alt - Shift and Ctrl - shift are key combinations that existed way before win - space did.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but hey... And I was convinced that Windows-Space did something with the gaming bar in Win10, or some such thing?

Comment: Yes, I believe that this Alt combination existed before, but I prefer the Win+space shortcut and UI on the taskbar, unfortunately I have to swap keyboards all the time...

Comment: Well... suddenly resumed itself to the initial state. All is fine!...